# Cron job doesn't execute php file and normal file

Tags: php, cron

I have two files, that needs to be executed every evening.

PHP file contains the latest records from database, and creates a source file in same directory.

And a normal file, even doesnt execute.

I tried to check in `/var/log/syslog`. found that below.

### Log file

```
Jul 29 13:56:01 ocs2 CRON[7016]: (root) CMD (/opt/lampp/bin/php /opt/lampp/htdocs/ats/cron_jobs/export_db_elastic.php)
Jul 29 13:57:01 ocs2 CRON[7118]: (root) CMD (source /opt/lampp/htdocs/ats/cron_jobs/tt2)
Jul 29 13:57:01 ocs2 CRON[7117]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

### PHP file contains code for creating a normal file

```
$db = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database) or die('Error connecting to DB : ' . mysqli_error($db));        

$q1 = "select * from elasticsearch_record where id = 1";
$q2 = "select max(id) as `max_num` from resumes";

$r1 = mysqli_query($db, $q1);
$r2 = mysqli_query($db, $q2);

if ($r1->num_rows > 0) {

    $rd1 = mysqli_fetch_array($r1);
    $rd2 = mysqli_fetch_array($r2);

    $start = $rd1['max_count'];
    $end = $rd2['max_num'];

    $one_up = $end + 1;

    $q3 = "update elasticsearch_record set max_count = '$one_up' where id = 1";
    $r3 = mysqli_query($db, $q3);


    $string1 = "bin=/root/elasticsearch-jdbc-1.6.0.0/bin\n";
    $string1 .= "lib=/root/elasticsearch-jdbc-1.6.0.0/lib\n";
    $string1 .= "echo '{\n";
    $string1 .= "\"type\" : \"jdbc\",\n";
    $string1 .= "\"jdbc\" : {\n";
    $string1 .= "\"url\" : \"jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.17:3306/c270751_resume\",\n";
    $string1 .= "\"user\" : \"ServerUser\",\n";
    $string1 .= "\"password\" : \"passwordhere\",\n";
    $string1 .= "\"sql\" : \"select * from resumes limit $start, $end\",\n";
    $string1 .= "\"index\" : \"rforceresumes\",\n";
    $string1 .= "\"type\" : \"resumetype\"\n";
    $string1 .= "}\n";
    $string1 .= "}' | java \\\n";
    $string1 .= "-cp \"\${lib}/*\" \\\n";
    $string1 .= "-Dlog4j.configurationFile=\${bin}/log4j2.xml \\\n";
    $string1 .= "org.xbib.tools.Runner \\\n";
    $string1 .= "org.xbib.tools.JDBCImporter";


    // echo "<pre>$string1</pre>";

    $myfile = fopen("tt2", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($myfile, $string1);
    fclose($myfile);


} else {
    die("Do Nothing");
}
```

### Normal file for Elasticsearch bulk import

```
bin=/root/elasticsearch-jdbc-1.6.0.0/bin
lib=/root/elasticsearch-jdbc-1.6.0.0/lib
echo '{
"type" : "jdbc",
"jdbc" : {
"url" : "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.17:3306/c270751_resume",
"user" : "ServerUser",
"password" : "passwordhere",
"sql" : "select * from resumes limit 1, 222504",
"index" : "rforceresumes",
"type" : "resumetype"
}
}' | java \
-cp "${lib}/*" \
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=${bin}/log4j2.xml \
org.xbib.tools.Runner \
org.xbib.tools.JDBCImporter
```

Now, I feel that these files are not executing with CRON, even though its displayed in log files.
Because, `normal file` modified date doesnt reflect.

### Below is the code for Cron Job

```
56 13 * * * /opt/lampp/bin/php /opt/lampp/htdocs/ats/cron_jobs/export_db_elastic.php
57 13 * * * source /opt/lampp/htdocs/ats/cron_jobs/tt2
```

I have no idea, even thought. i verified my code lot of time. 
Why isnt executed properly.

### Note:

When i run it manually through terminal or browser. its working perfect.